# boomi atom is running but not visible on browser

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, boomi

I have started the dell boomi atom on my ubuntu18.04 machine. i have pulled the boomi/atom image through docker and running it on 9090 port. Though the container is up and running, i am unable to see the boomi on my browser with 9090 port. when i check the container logs i am getting the "/home/boomi/startatom.sh: line 20: atom: command not found" and "/home/boomi/startatom.sh: line 28: atom: command not found" error.

I manually downloaded the atomdocker64-install.sh file and run it. there also i am getting the same error.

Comment: Are these two files available at the exact location in the your docker container? /home/boomi/startatom.sh and /home/boomi/startatom.sh